# writing an existing Matlab for loop in Python

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop

I have the following Matlab code and im trying to write that in python but in Python i can't call ,, i ,, like in Matlab.

Is there a way to write that in Python?

```
for i=1:np-1
    ip1=floor(xp(i)*(nx-1))+1;ip2=floor(xp(i+1)*(nx-1))+1;
    jp1=floor(yp(i)*(ny-1))+1;jp2=floor(yp(i+1)*(ny-1))+1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you tried very hard.

```
for i in range(np):
    ip1 = int( xp[i]   * (nx-1)) + 1
    ip2 = int( xp[i+1] * (nx-1)) + 1
    jp1 = int( yp[i]   * (ny-1)) + 1
    jp2 = int( yp[i+1] * (ny-1)) + 1
```

Of course, the loop is kind of useless because the four variables are overwritten each time through the loop.